# An Android rival for iPhone 5s?

Tags: smartphones

Are there any good small android smartphones? I've been using LG G2 Mini for almost two years now, and it has always seemed too big for me (neither am I happy with its performance).

To be honest, what I'm looking for is a phone that:

1. is small (given the current trend, the smaller the better)
2. has Android
3. works well with Pokemon Go (good performance and battery). :D

I've used a little bit of iPhone 5s and it's just what I want, but Apple OS slightly plays on my nerves. Is there any Android phone that can compete with it over size, performance and battery?

A decent size of internal memory is also welcomed. My old LG G2 Mini got completely stuck even though I moved literally everything I could to the SD card.

Comment: How big is too big? 5.5 inches seems the common size now.

Comment: Yup, and this fact is driving me mad. I don't know why people are so fond of bricks, especially when most of them also have a tablet. I prefer my cellphone to be handy.

Answer (score 1):

So, this isn't the smallest 4" phone, but I was amazed to find a phone like this, so I'm going to put it out here because I wasn't aware these kinds of phones existed - I recommend the **[Sonim XP7](http://www.gsmarena.com/sonim_xp7-6828.php)**. This phone is kind of a monster. It's a little short on the internal memory at 16gb with no way to add more, so that is a concern, but... this thing has a 40h talk time. That's crazy. It's also very well reviewed for its GPS performance. The CPU and RAM match or beat the 5s. But yeah, it is a little bigger, and yeah, it doesn't really match up in terms of storage capacity. Still, you can find it on the [used market](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Sonim-XP7700-Built-For-Life-Military-Grade-AT-T-/272277419683?_trksid=p2352135.m2548.l4275) for pretty darn cheap. [Here's a comparison](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=6828&idPhone2=5685&idPhone3=6077) across all the considered devices.

Comment: @BigElittles If you look at Adam's profile, all is explained there.